# Normal vector for tangent plane if we have function of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

### Problem

if i have $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $w:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and for example if we have $f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2$ $$ f(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2 $$ $$ x^3+3xy^2-f(x,y)=0 $$we can mark this as function of $w(x,y,f(x,y))$
$$ w(x,y,z)=x^3+3xy^2-f(x,y) $$ Is it true that:

$$ \nabla w(x,y,z)=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\delta}{\delta x} x^3 \\ \frac{\delta}{\delta y} 3xy^2 \\ \frac{\delta}{\delta f(x,y)} (-f(x,y)) \end{bmatrix} $$
in every situation $\nabla(x,y,z)$ is normal vector for tangent plane of $f(x,y)$

---

This is something that my intuition would tell me this is correct but i don't have definitive proof of this. If someone could confirm this / confirm this is wrong that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Something has gone wrong: The third component of your expression is $\frac{d}{dz} f(x, y) = 0$.

Comment: @Travis hmm the $f(x,y)$ component should be always $-1$ something has gone wrong indeed

Comment: @Travis i think i meant to say that the partial derivative of $z$ component should be $\frac{\delta}{\delta f(x,y)}$. It should be treated as a single variable i don't know if this is correct notation ?